# Is there a way to run shell command only once a year?

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

I have a shell script inside Jenkins job where I need that only one command inside the script will run only once a year every year. Something like:

```
if [today is 1st of Nov in any Year]; then
 do this command....
fi
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. You have a Jenkins job consisting of a single step, which is a shell script you want executed once a year, or you have a frequently run or multi-step Jenkins job for which only one step needs to be executed once a year? The latter sounds like a bad design/requirements, but based on the snippet is plausible..

Answer (score 1):

The `date` utility in conjunction with a string test should do the trick:

```
case $(date +%m%d) in
  (1101) run this command
esac
```

For the formats that date(1) accepts, see the strftime(3) manual page.

Comment: With your preliminary work, that would also be possible: `if [[ $(date +%m%d) == 1101 ]]; then echo 'today is the day'; fi` or with `bash` version >= 4.2: `printf -v x "%(%m%d)T"; if [[ "$x" == "1101" ]]; then echo 'today is the day'; fi`

Comment: @Cyrus Yes, but I'd avoid the bashisms for portability. It is easy in this case: `if [ $(date +%m%d) = 1101 ]; then ...; fi`. I like the `case` version more because it is easy to extend for more than one date and allows for wildcarding.

Answer (score 1):

Schedule your job using the Build Periodically [cron syntax](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#cron-syntax).

For each **Nov. 1**, use syntax below. `@yearly` will run once a year, but you don't have control on when (date or time), but will run once a year thereafter at same date/time.

```
triggers {
    cron('H * 1 11 *')
}
```

[image: Build Periodically]
[image: Build Yearly]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Jenkins and this is a job that runs once a year, you can move the script into a Jenkins job and remove the `if` conditions. Then, under the "build triggers" section you can choose the option to build periodically. Cron expressions are supported here, or you could simply use `@yearly`. Doing this will show something like:

```
Would last have run at Sunday, September 11, 2022 10:21:52 PM CEST; would next run at Monday, September 11, 2023 10:21:52 PM CEST.
```

Which should hopefully be what you're looking for.